# Malformed [tag:] elements freeze the markdown preview

Tags: bug, editor, markdown-preview

Using Chrome on Windows. When I enter the following text in the editor, the markdown preview stops working, frozen, until the page is reloaded:

<kbd>[</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

It also happens if I precede `[` and/or `:` with a `\`. Sometimes I don't need the closing `]`, but I cannot put my finger on the reason for that.

Additionally, if the above is entered into the editor and then posted, and then that post is edited, the markdown preview does not appear at all.

Comment: Wow. Nice find.

Comment: Interesting , something of a loophole here?

Comment: Looks like it's been acknowledged , but not fixed